# Dynamic Java Object From Database with field , values and data type

Tags: java, database, reflection

I am creating a JAVA Spring Boot app where we are saving all the fields name, values , data type and validation of Fields in database.

Now I want to create Java Object with these dynamic data.

What will be the best way to achieve success in this situation !

Comment: Please clarify/narrow down your question and provide a [reprex] so that we can give you a precise answer.

Comment: Have you defined Java classes for the incoming data? Or are you saying the incoming data is arbitrary, and you don’t know its structure and therefore would like to create new Java classes in-the-fly at runtime? Edit your Question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ORM tool such as hibernate along with JPA to do this easily.

You can get an idea of it from these links
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-oracle

Comment: Hibernate can dynamically create classes?